# Find volume with triple integral

Tags: integration, volume, spherical-coordinates

I want to find the volume of $ (x^2 + y^2)^3 + z^6 =a^3xyz $.

I changed the basis like that: $ x = r \sin ^ \frac{1}{3} B \cos A; y = r \sin ^ \frac{1}{3} B \sin A; z = r \cos ^ \frac{1}{3} B $ (similar to spherical coordinates), so the equalation changed to $ r^3 = a^3 \sin ^ \frac{2}{3} B \cos ^ \frac{1}{3} B \cos A \sin A $. But when I took integral with $A=0..2\pi; B=0..\frac {\pi} {2}; r=0.. (a^3 \sin ^ \frac{2}{3} B \cos ^ \frac{1}{3} B \cos A \sin A)^\frac {1} {3}$ and Jacobian $= \frac {-r^2 \cos {2b} }{3 \cos ^ \frac{2}{3} B \sin ^ \frac{1}{3} B}$ I got $0$ as the answer. Would be nice if you showed me the mistake or another method, thanks.

Comment: In your equation $r^3=a^3...$ you appear to have switched $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg ye, fixed. Just a typo, it's switched in basis.

Comment: Could you show the steps leading to the integral.  Wild guess - integral over $A$ leads to $0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes, you right. The answer on the last step is $ \frac {- \pi a^3 \cos ^ 2 A}{54 \sqrt {3}} $ with $A=0..2 \pi $. But the borders seemed logical.

Comment: It is not clear (to me) what defines the volume you are integrating over.  I suspect your integration limits are not right.

Comment: I believe I got it right - see answer.

Comment: Are you sure about the $B$ integration range?  Usual spherical coordinates have a half circle, not quarter circle,

Comment: @herbsteinberg then we get some complex values as $ \sqrt {-1} $ appears in integration result

Comment: Are you sure - there are no square roots, only cube roots and its powers, which are real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\le A\le\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\pi\le A\le \frac{3\pi}{2}$, $r\ge 0$, For the other half of the $A$ domain, $r\le 0$.  Therefore the $A$ integration has to be split up into four parts so that each part integrates to a positive result.

Caveat:  I am still not sure what the figure looks like.

Comment: For fixed $B$ the cross-section looks like a four leaf clover.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you set $x = r \sin ^ \frac{1}{3} B \cos A$? What does that even mean, and what does it have to do with spherical coordinates?

I would expect something like $x = r \sin B \cos A.$

Comment: Just to reduce equalation as we got $ \sin^2 + \cos ^2 $ twice. It's not exactly spherical coordinates, but it is using the same logic.